# Cheapest way of managing relational SQL data

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm trying to find the best method for managing the huge-relational game data.

Let me explain my data structure.

There are three main data field. User, Bets and Coupons.

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                     bets                           |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | status    | yes             | no              |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 0         | 1.45            | 2.52            |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 1         | 3.00            | 1.08            |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+                    
| 3  | 2         | 2.43            | 1.42            |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+

+----------------------------------------------------+
|                     coupons                        |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | played_by | bets            | status          |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1         |1,yes;2,no;3,yes;| 0               |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 2         |2,yes;3,no;1,no; | 0               |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+                    
| 3  | 3         |1,yes;2,no;      | 0               |
+----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**Information:** Every bet has yes/no choice. Users play bets. We register them inside of coupons. If all bets inside a coupon WIN, coupon wins and user get extra balance. Classic. Please note that there will be so many bets (avg. 5 per coupon), so many coupons played by users (thousands), and thousands of users.

So I'm trying to find best method for **finalizing bets and checking coupons for win or lose process.**

**Method 1 I tried;**

- We finalized Bet ID: 2 as yes;
- Check 2,yes; with "LIKE" operator in *coupon*, if there is, concat(append) 1 to *progress* field.
- Check how many bets are there inside the *coupon*.
- If count of 1s equals to numbers of bet inside this coupon, set coupon status to WON.

**Method 2 I tried;**

- Finalize bets; YES or NO
- Check related coupons with a cron task.

I liked both methods, but I want users see their progress immediately, so I am not sure about the cron method. Both methods work fine, but I have doubts what will happen when there are thousands of users.

I hope I described my issue understandable. I'm looking for comments and suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Word "cheapest" in title doesn't make much sense.  It looks like, at a minimum, you REALLY need to refactor your schema to normalize out the bet to coupon relationship.  Unfortunately to best have discussion around what schema may make most sense, you really have to have an understanding for all the different use cases you have for retrieving/displaying this data.  That sort of analysis would make for a very broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending a user's bet to a value in a coupon (which is highly inefficient since you're having to use the `LIKE` operator), it makes more sense to just create a table of coupons that store the ID of the bet its associated with it, the ID of the user it belongs to, and the value of the coupon (YES or NO). So your `Coupon` table would look like the following:

```
Coupons

ID  BetID   UserID  Value
1   1       10      YES
2   1       11      NO
```

Now if you want to acquire all of the coupons associated with Bet #1, you would just do a `SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE BetID=1`.

If Bet #1 wins, all you would need to do is acquire the value of the bet for the winning choice, and update all of the users who fall under the choice. For example:

```
# Select the winning value:

SELECT <winning value>
FROM bets
WHERE id = <id of completed bet>;

# Update the users:

UPDATE users
SET balance = balance + <winning value>
WHERE id EXISTS (SELECT userID from coupons where betID = <id of completed bet> AND value='<winning value>');
```

Comment: But there are multiple bets in a coupon?

Comment: And I'm only finalizing one of them at once.

Comment: Implementation-wise, it may be wiser to just create another row in the coupons table. If you really need to have a sort of "package" or "repository" of coupons, create a CouponRepository or CouponCollection that manages multiple coupons.